# Is the neutral pion a singlet?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, representation-theory, pions, isospin-symmetry

In Griffiths' [*Introduction to Elementary Particles*](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Wb9DYrjcoKAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=griffiths%20elementary%20particles&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dO2XU5-DENWXuATop4DYDw&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=griffiths%20elementary%20particles&f=false), it is mentioned p. 179 that the $\pi^0$ is a singlet under $SU(2)$ isospin. But it is also part of the $\pi^-,\pi^0,\pi^+$ isospin triplet. How can it be both?

Don't particles of a given $SU(2)$ multiplet mix under a corresponding transformation?

Comment: It is on p 170. It is an alarming (and shameful!) "typo".  He means η, (5.92), and ***not*** π0, (5.91). It is hard to catch, but, frankly, inexcusable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a travesty of overlapping historical notations, we have both [strong isospin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isospin), under which the neutron and proton are the two projections of the nucleon and are raised and lowered by the pion, and [weak isospin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_isospin), in which the left-handed parts of the $(u,d)$, $(e,\nu_e)$, $(c,s)$, $(\mu, \nu_\mu)$, $(t,b)$, and $(\tau,\nu_\tau)$ doublets are raised and lowered by the $W^\pm$ bosons.  The six right-handed quarks and the six right-handed leptons are weak isospin singlets.

It is possible in principle (I think) for a particle like
the $\pi^0$ to be the neutral member of a strong isospin triplet, but a singlet under weak isospin.

However, that doesn't seem to be the case for the $\pi^0$. The "lowering operator" vertex $\pi^\pm \leftrightarrow W^\pm\pi^0$ actually does exist, as evidenced by the existence of the decay mode $\pi^+\to \pi^0 e^+ \nu_e$, which has branching ratio $10^{-8}$.  You have a fresh comment suggesting that your textbook makes this claim incorrectly.

Comment: Nice answer! How can you show that it is a singlet under weak isospin?

Comment: I was afraid you'd ask that, that's where my memory goes squishy.  It may be as simple as observing that the $\pi^0$ can't couple to a $W^+$ due to charge conservation.

Comment: Excessively academic nitpick: I *think* I can see a survining $ZZ\pi^0\pi^0$ vertex, but I could be wrong there...

Comment: @CosmasZachos Non-academic non-nitpick: the $W^\pm\pi^0$ vertex is actually allowed, and the isospin-lowering decays actually do happen (though they are kinematically and energetically suppressed). This very old answer (v1) was wrong; I've edited. There is no need to hunt for a double-weak vertex. Single-weak $\pi Z$ vertices contribute to parity violation in purely hadronic weak interactions, but when I left that field the theory situation was kind of an inscrutable mess.

Comment: How embarrassing I skipped it... $g W^+_\mu \pi^- \partial^\mu \pi^0$, and the likes, alright...

Answer (score 2):

$\pi^0$ is a singlet under $SU(2)$ isospin because if you interchange the u by d (as a rotation in 2- dimensional flavor space) then you will not be able to mix up $\pi^0$ with any other pion, and hence it is a singlet. It is in this sense you should understand it.

Comment: Hmmm, but strong isospin also rotates u into d, and takes the $\pi^0$ to $\pi^\pm$.  I have a vague memory of something subtle involving a negative sign appearing under strong isospin rotations; I don't remember that argument well enough to decide whether it applies to weak isospin, or whether that's the difference.

Comment: The neutral pion ***does couple*** to  he other pions, as manifest in hundreds of terms in the chiral lagrangian. This is a thoroughgoingly specious argument.

Answer (score 1):

The pi zero is not a singlet, but part of an Ispin triplet.  The eta meson and the omega meson are Ispin SU(2) singlets.

Comment: +1 Absolutely spot on! The author must have proofread sloppily on  p. 170.